# How to switch to html within iframe using Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to click on the extension popup.
which does have HTML within an iframe, and another iframe with HTML inside the first iframe.

Can you actually do this using XPath?

```
<iframe id="1">
  <html>
    <iframe id="2">
     <html>

       This is where the element I need is.

     </html>
    </iframe>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are called nested `iframe` which is `iframe` inside an `iframe`.

Simply `switch` to **first one** then **second one** :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("1")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("2")));
driver.findElement(By.id("element id which you want to interact");
```

remember to switch to default content once you are done with iframe.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that doesn't really work if there is a second non-root HTML tag. I don't know why.

Comment: What's the error ? can I have page url ?

Comment: It's an extension I open through ID,

Everything within the second HTML is unreachable for me...

https://i.imgur.com/R4kNJwn.png

Comment: I can see only one frame in that picture, also that does not have id as 1 or 2, so you'll have to replace that with `IFRAME_ID`